# serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout Pico with linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, pyserial, raspberry-pi-pico, stepper

I have a Pico Microcontroller that is connected to a stepper motor driver, and I just want to rotate the motor on command.

My code is able to do that when it is connected to a Mac system, but whenever I am connecting that to a Linux system (Ubuntu 22), the write function throws this error, and the motor rotates only a bit.

`serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout`

Let me share the values that my connection object have
`Serial<id=0x7f9557bd81c0, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyACM1', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=10.0, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)`

Command that I am using to write:
'motor.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.DOUBLE)
\x0c'

Here is the code from the library which is throwing the code:

```
    def write(self, data):
        """Output the given byte string over the serial port."""
        if not self.is_open:
            raise PortNotOpenError()
        d = to_bytes(data)
        tx_len = length = len(d)
        timeout = Timeout(self._write_timeout)
        while tx_len > 0:
            try:
                n = os.write(self.fd, d)
                if timeout.is_non_blocking:
                    # Zero timeout indicates non-blocking - simply return the
                    # number of bytes of data actually written
                    return n
                elif not timeout.is_infinite:
                    # when timeout is set, use select to wait for being ready
                    # with the time left as timeout
                    if timeout.expired():
                        raise SerialTimeoutException('Write timeout')
                    abort, ready, _ = select.select([self.pipe_abort_write_r], [self.fd], [], timeout.time_left())
                    if abort:
                        os.read(self.pipe_abort_write_r, 1000)
                        break
                    if not ready:
 ===>This Line          raise SerialTimeoutException('Write timeout')
                else:
                    assert timeout.time_left() is None
                    # wait for write operation
                    abort, ready, _ = select.select([self.pipe_abort_write_r], [self.fd], [], None)
                    if abort:
                        os.read(self.pipe_abort_write_r, 1)
                        break
                    if not ready:
                        raise SerialException('write failed (select)')
                d = d[n:]
                tx_len -= n
            except SerialException:
                raise
            except OSError as e:
                # this is for Python 3.x where select.error is a subclass of
                # OSError ignore BlockingIOErrors and EINTR. other errors are shown
                # https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475.
                if e.errno not in (errno.EAGAIN, errno.EALREADY, errno.EWOULDBLOCK, errno.EINPROGRESS, errno.EINTR):
                    raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))
            except select.error as e:
                # this is for Python 2.x
                # ignore BlockingIOErrors and EINTR. all errors are shown
                # see also http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#select
                if e[0] not in (errno.EAGAIN, errno.EALREADY, errno.EWOULDBLOCK, errno.EINPROGRESS, errno.EINTR):
                    raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))
            if not timeout.is_non_blocking and timeout.expired():
                raise SerialTimeoutException('Write timeout')
        return length - len(d)
```